# SQL Query Analyzer: How can I check database compatability mode?

Tags: query-analyzer

How can I check database compatability mode in query analyzer version 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this SQL Server 2000? If so:

```
SELECT cmptlevel FROM master..sysdatabases WHERE name = db_name()
```

For SQL Server 2005 and 2008, as per Mitch Wheat, i.e.:

```
SELECT compatibility_level 
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE name = db_name()
```

In all versions, this works as well:

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel '{insert name of your database here}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select compatibility_level 
from sys.databases 
where name = db_name()
```